# passing information from browser's tab to a chrome extension with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm attempting to pass data from a web-page (current opened tab) to my extension.

I have the following manifest.json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0",
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "default_icon": "logo192.png",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "open"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["notifications"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["contentScript.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ],

  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

I also have a very simple background.js and contentScript.js files.

As far as i understand, the contentScript starts running when a webpage (which fits the 'matches' property in the manifest) is loaded.

So, I'm trying to do something very simple, such as sending the title of a certain web-page to the extension.

So far I have this line of code in my contentScript.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerText);
```

which sends data to the isolated environment of background.js, well, at least it is supposed to. In my case, for some odd reason it doesn't show anything on 'Inspect views service worker'.

Beyond the fact that I don't know why it doesn't pass this information to the background.js, I was also wondering how from background.js can I pass the/a data to the extension itself, in such way it'll appear there?

### **EDIT**:

well, I'm actually able to retrieve the title in the isolated environment of background.js, but the question still remains as for how do I pass this information to the extension itself?

Regards!

Comment: You will only see something if you print it or debug the code. You need to use onMessage listener in your background script as shown in the documentation. Also note that after the background script terminates due to inactivity the console.log is cleared, but you can use console.warn and inspect the output in chrome://extensions page after clicking the Errors button.

Comment: Edited the question. I did log the information, and it actually appears. I still remain with the question of how to pass it to the extension and use it there.

Comment: You already passed the info. Please clarify the question further.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer :) I have edited the question, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: It's not clearer but I guess you want to pass the info to the action page, which runs only when shown so it can't receive messages otherwise. In this case you can use chrome.storage or reverse the direction of messaging and instead do it from the popup. Note that you don't need a content script to read the tab's title: just use chrome.tabs.query.

Comment: Yep. That's what I meant. By the way, how can I do it ? After reading chrome.tabs api, I can see that I can get all tabs, for example, but I haven't seen anything regarding finding a specific tab.

Comment: See the documentation for [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), it has the examples. The code is broken though: `await` should be after `=`.

Comment: message should be a JSON-ifiable object. but you pass only string;
`chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg:"elemtitle",data:datadocument.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerText});`